# carriage return by fgets

Tags: c, string, fgets, carriage-return

I am running the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<io.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp=fopen("test.txt","r"))==NULL){
        printf("File can't be read\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char str[50];
    fgets(str,50,fp);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

text.txt contains: `I am a boy\r\n`

Since I am on Windows, it takes \r\n as a new line character and so if I read this from a file it should store `"I am a boy\n\0"` in `str`, but I get `"I am a boy\r\n"`. I am using mingw compiler.

Comment: How are you determining the content of `str`? Your program never seems to investigate that.

Comment: By printing and it must not show '\r' right?

Comment: `fgets` will include the new line characters plus a null terminator, so the output you get is perfectly fine.

Comment: @netcoder But I am getting carriage return also which I should not get.

Comment: No, you should get the carriage return, that is the correct behaviour.  *it takes \r\n as a new line character* is incorrect, it takes \n as a new line character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since I am on Windows, it takes \r\n as a new line character...

This assumption is wrong. The C standard treats carriage return and new line as two different things, as evidenced in C99 §5.2.1/3 (Character sets):

> [...] In the basic execution character set, there shall be
>   control characters representing alert, backspace, carriage return, and new-line. [...]

The `fgets` function description is as follows, in C99 §7.19.7.2/2:

> The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n
>   from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s. **No additional
>   characters are read *after a new-line* character (which is retained)** or after end-of-file. A
>   null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

Therefore, when encountering the string `I am a boy\r\n`, a conforming implementation should read up to the `\n` character. There is no possibly sane reason why the implementation should discard `\r` based on the platform.

Comment: ok thanx @netcoder. I read that Windows takes \r\n as a new line character, so I was in confusion.

Answer (score 10):

The behavior depends on the c library implementation and which mode you pass to `fopen`. See this quote from the MSDN documentation on `fopen` [(fopen on MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yeby3zcb.aspx):

> b - Open in binary (untranslated) mode; translations involving carriage-return and linefeed characters are suppressed.

Means, if you use the Microsoft c library, and open your file omitting the 'b', the carriage return characters will be removed from the stream.

Since you're using mingw, your compiler probably links against the GNU c library which follows the POSIX standard. This is what the GNU documentation says about `fopen` [(fopen on gnu.org)](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html):

> The character ‘b’ in opentype has a standard meaning; it requests a binary stream rather than a text stream. But this makes no difference in POSIX systems (including GNU systems).

Concluding: you're omitting the 'b' mode char, which opens your stream in text mode. You're on Windows but use a GNU c library which makes no difference between text and binary mode. This is why `fgets` reads both carriage return and new line.

Answer (score 2):

The c standard says this about text streams in (among other things):

> Characters may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to
> conform to differing conventions for representing text in the host
> environment. Thus, there need not be a one-to-one correspondence between the
> characters in a stream and those in the external representation. Data read in
> from a text stream will necessarily compare equal to the data that were
> earlier written out to that stream only if: the data consist only of printing
> characters and the control characters horizontal tab and new-line; no new-line
> character is immediately preceded by space characters; and the last character
> is a new-line character.

In other words, if a file is opened in text mode, an implementation is free to add, remove and modify control characters if it wants/needs to when going to and from disk. Which is apparently what the microsoft implementation does with the carriage return, but the gnu implementation doesn't.