# fgets adds an interrogation mark

Tags: c, fgets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [carriage return by fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769289/carriage-return-by-fgets)

I have this code:

```
char arch[80];
fgets (arch, sizeof(arch), stdin);
```

When I access the value of `arch` it shows the value I have entered from `stdin` followed by an interrogation mark, why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that it represents the `\n` line terminator in whatever you use to examine the value of `arch`. SO has *a lot* of questions regarding the line termination, I'm sure you can easily find *a number* of ways to deal with it.

Comment: what is SO? I thought fgets would be better than scanf... I'm trying to get a file name from the standard input and i dont want a '?' on it.

Comment: SO is stack overflow. Stripping the newline is as easy as `arch[strlen(arch)-1]=0`, provided you know it's there.

Answer (score 4):

`fgets()` stores the trailing newline:

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream  and
>   stores  them  into  the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
>   EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the  buffer.
>   A '\0' is stored after the last character in the buffer.

If you are inspecting the variable in some kind of debugger, it's possible that the newline gets displayed as "?", or whatever you mean by "interrogation mark".