# Exclude the blank value from an input that split into array in STDIN PHP

Tags: php, stdin

I tried to split an input

```
<?php
$hand = fgets(STDIN);
$hand_convert = str_split($hand);
print_r($hand_convert);
?>
```

I got this two blank value

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\coding-test\Soal 1>php search.php
asd
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => s
    [2] => d
    [3] =>
    [4] =>

)
```

There is two added blank value at the end of array. I believe that i just enter 3 word, but it return 5 index. Where the two blank value add came from ?

i got this type of data using `var_dump`

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\coding-test\Soal 1>php search.php
asd
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "s"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [3]=>
" string(1) "
  [4]=>
  string(1) "
"
}
```

I tried to remove it using `array_filter` but it still gave me the two blank values.

```
<?php
$hand = fgets(STDIN);
$hand_convert = str_split($hand);
print_r(array_filter($hand_convert));
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump` your array.

Comment: try to use the trim() which will remove the extra space from the string (STDIN in your case) if exists.

Comment: @u_mulder updated question

Comment: So, these are linebreaks, which are __not__ empty values. Use `trim`, as @WaqasAhmed proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try trimming your value before you split the string:

```
<?php
$hand = fgets(STDIN);
$hand_convert = str_split(trim($hand));
print_r($hand_convert);
```

Also, your attempt with `array_filter` did not work because this function removes everything that is empty, in other words, everything that `empty() === true`. As `empty("\n") === false` it did not remove.

Comment: do you know why PHP included the linbreaks in STDIN ?

Comment: @Gagantous there is a good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769289/carriage-return-by-fgets