# Best way to read this file while ignoring the new line character

Tags: c, file, parsing, file-io, newline

Here's the file I want to read.

```
single
splash
single
V-Line
h-line
```

Macro for checking if string is equal.

```
#define STR_MATCH(a,b) (strncmp((a),(b),strlen(b)+1) == 0)
```

Here's what i'm using to read it.

```
void readMissilesFile(char* fileName)
{
    FILE* mFile;
    char missile[7];

    /* Open the file. */
    mFile = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (mFile != NULL)
    {
        while (!feof(mFile))
        {
            fgets(missile, 7, mFile);
            if (!(STR_MATCH(missile, "\n")))
            {
                printf("Missile: %s", missile);
            }
        }
        fclose(mFile);
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Could not open the file.");
    }
}
```

So i'm having difficulties as its printing out spaces when I read the line. I tried to ignore this by ensuring it only reads 7 characters which is the max length of each missile. Then I made a macro called strcmp which just checks if they are equal(to hopefully not print it).

Please find the macro attached as well.

Thanks in advance and any help is great. :)

Comment: You are only reading 6 characters + null terminator. Your lines include newline so you don't get that until you call fgets again. Leave more space for your line.

Comment: Changed that to no avail. I had experimented with that earlier.

Comment: FYI: [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can replace the newline characters by using [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn).

You should not use `feof` like this, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) explains why. A safe way to read the file till the end is to use `fgets` as stop condition in the while loop.

The container, `missile` should be one `char` bigger than the max size of the largest string to accomodate for `'\0'`.

[**Live sample**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/TidyLinedBooleanvalue)

```
#include <string.h>
//...
char missile[10];
//...
if (mFile != NULL)
{
    while (fgets(missile, 10, mFile)) //will read till there are no more lines
    {
        missile[strcspn(missile, "\r\n")] = '\0'; //remove newline characters
        printf("Missile: %s ", missile);
    }
}
//...
```

I would advise the reading of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769289/carriage-return-by-fgets) which has detailed info about `fgets`, namely the issue of newline characters consumption.

Comment: It's more or less the answer I was about to write. I just suggest mentioning `\r` (so using `strcspn` also with it) in order to make sure to have the expected output also on Windows (see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769289/11336762).

Comment: @RobertoCaboni, I added your good sugestions to the answer, in the future feel free to improve my posts if you feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

There is `getline` function in `stdio.h` which reads line until delimiter. Its a POSIX though, so if you are on Windows you may lack it.

Here is example implementation:
https://github.com/ivanrad/getline/blob/master/getline.c

Comment: So your best shot is to write something similar (i.e. read character by character until you find '\n')